# How to install cyanogen on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 (Verizon)

Tags: cyanogenmod

I *think* I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 (Verizon)

On samsung website it's http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-T537VYKAVZW

I went through all the steps and did a:

adb sideload cm-10.1-20140216-NIGHTLY-p4vzw.zip

But I got red errors like:

```
"E:footer is wrong"

"E:failed to verify whole-file signature"

"E:signature verification failed"
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Do I even have the right zip file?

Comment: p4vzw is Galaxy Tab, not Galaxy Tab 4 https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/P4vzw_Info

Comment: ah thank u! So, does the right zip exist for Tab 4? Or do I have to make it?